# MongoDB Compass forces me to enter Replica Set Name when trying to connect to my local DB. Can I avoid this?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

EDIT:

Not sure what I've done differently (again, these are my first steps with all of this), but now I don't get the error message I got before. Instead though, it just tries to make the connection and I get

`Server selection timed out after 30000 ms`

After some time.

ORIGINAL:

I am new to using MongoDB - currently taking a back end course online.

It seems that Compass has changed their interface for adding a new connection, lately, and maybe some business logic, because all guides I find use the previous one.

Specifically, when adding a new connection, in the guides I read, they leave `Replica Set Name` empty. When I try to do that, I get an error saying `Incomplete key value pair for option`.

I tried just calling it `localhost` and it "works", but I don't see any of my DBs.
If I connect with Robo 3t I can see them.

Is it a wrong `Replica Set Name` that's preventing me from deeing the DBs? Or am I doing something else wrong?

My settings for when trying to connect are:

```
Hostname : `localhost`
port : 27017
SRV record : I leave it off
Authentication : None
Replica Set Name : localhost
Read preferences : Primary
SSl : none
SSL tunnel : None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Compass requires a replica set name to be specified, based on the following message I get when I specify a single host which happens to be a secondary:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: 'not master and slaveOk=false': It is recommended to change your read preference in the connection dialog to Primary Preferred or Secondary Preferred or provide a replica set name for a full topology connection.

"Server selection timed out" can mean different things:

- There isn't a database running.
- The database is running but you entered the wrong port number.
- Compass attempted to perform a specific operation which required a certain server type (e.g. a primary or a secondary). The database is running and there's a server listening at the port you specified, but it is of the wrong type.

Hard to say which of these is the case just going by the error message.

Comment: I am not sure what I've changed, but now I don't get this error anymore. Instead I just get a timeout error.

Comment: If you already created a connection, Compass appears to show old (cached) data when it can't connect. If you hover over the right UI element it might tell you that it couldn't connect.

Comment: I haven't made a local connection before. I don't see any cached data (I don't see any data at all).
I have no problem connecting to Atlas though, which is weird, because it seems that this is what most people have problems with, but I had none. It's only connecting to my local DB that's causing me these issues.

Comment: Note also you can use URI to connect locally, e.g. mongodb://localhost and mongodb://localhost:27017/db .

Comment: I'm not sure which is it, but I've resterted the server and used `mongodb://localhost:27017/db` to connect and it works now! Cheers

Comment: Compass doesn't require a replica set name. Also please post the version of Compass you are using when reporting problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem working on a single machine for development as a replica set member(primary). I did this because I had to use `@Transactional` of *spring-data-mongodb*. What solved for me was logging to mongo shell and issuing:
`rs.initiate();`